# Coefficients (coeffs) in MATLAB for 0 coefficients of x^n

Tags: matlab, coefficients

```
syms x;
f = 6*x^6 - 25*x^5 + 31*x^4 - 31*x^2 + 25*x - 6;
cf = coeffs(f);
disp(cf);
```

for these peice of line I'm getting this as an output
`[-6, 25, -31, 31, -25, 6]`

But why I'm not getting 0 as coefficients of x^3,
while computing the roots of the from coefficients I need to have 0 as coefficients of x^3

output: `[-6, 25, -31, 31, -25, 6]`

my expectations: [-6, 25, -31, 0, 31, -25, 6]

Comment: coeffs(f,'All')

Comment: If the question was how, check documentation (this is not a long one). You may also be interested in `sym2poly` if all you want is the numeric coefficients of a single-variable polynomial. If the question is indeed on why, I think the `[C, T]=...` syntax may be related. It seems it's expected that users would get both the coefficients and the terms together in situations with missing terms.

Comment: As for roots, there are Matlab utilities for solving symbolic polynomial roots. Not sure if you should be the one operating on the coefficients unless you are leaving symbolic to numeric, in which case, use `sym2poly`.